# Fglrx broken package

Tags: fglrx

i've getting to not respond, where i can click the fglrx to install, but.  here's code.

```
$ sudo apt-get install fglrx 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fglrx : Depends: xorg-video-abi-11 but it is not installable or
                  xorg-video-abi-12 but it is not installable or
                  xorg-video-abi-13 but it is not installable or
                  xorg-video-abi-14 but it is not installable or
                  xorg-video-abi-15
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Try running `dpkg --configure -a` first. I had this problem, too, and I think that's how I fixed it.

Comment: @Zacharee1 it seem not respond.  or i may wrong, but shall i add it to sudo with that?

Comment: Sorry, yes. I tend to forget that, since I just go into `su`.

Comment: $ sudo dpkg --configure -a
user@user:~$

Comment: it not seem respond after that. @Zacharee1

Comment: post your ubuntu version and `apt-cache policy fglrx`

Comment: where i can add it to fixed. i have getting it worked by through IRC, where i can put it (Fixed)?

Answer (score 0):

I got this same issue when trying to install fglrx or fglrx-updates on my HP dv6-6117 just the other day. I ended up getting it to install by first running:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends xserver-xorg libgl1-mesa-glx libeg1-mesa-drivers
```

Just a word of warning, my touchpad was temporarily disabled after doing this and installing fglrx, but it did get fglrx to install.